# Custom file attribute Rest Api

Tags: magento2, orders, custom-options, rest-api, magento2.1.6

I'm using the Magento 2 rest API to read out the orders in to our system.
If an order line product have a custom file option we want to download this file.

From the order items we get the following custom option result:

> "option_value": "image/png,abu.png,custom_options/quote/a/b/2f25a9e4bb5afd53ad4e097c024289b6.png,custom_options/order/a/b/2f25a9e4bb5afd53ad4e097c024289b6.png,/var/www/html/magento2/pub/media/custom_options/quote/a/b/2f25a9e4bb5afd53ad4e097c024289b6.png,269733,651,718,2f25a9e4bb5afd53ad4e"

How can we download this file. The Magento backend uses the UUID and also a column id?

Question:
How can you download a file uploaded by the user from the rest API?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the information of the file exploding the "option_value", 
first element: File extension
second element: File Name
third: Download link (prepend: base_url + "media/")

eg:
File extension: png
File name: abu.png
Download link: /media/custom_options/quote/a/b/2f25a9e4bb5afd53ad4e097c024289b6.png